# Is it possible to get all events from all calendars regardless of calendar group

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I want to use a Graph request to pull all events from all calendars regardless of a calendar group. What I have tried:

```
GET /me/calendar/events
GET /me/calendarGroups/{id}/calendars/{id}/events
```

Case one I get from one calendar from the default calendar.
case two I get from a specific calendar in any group.
Any way of getting events from all calendars everywhere?

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all events from all user's calendars you can use Client Credential flow which gives App only token and use it to query all calendars using below call

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userid/calendars`

and then use the calendarid's and pull the events by using the below call for each calendar_id.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/1ab4e76f-5f52-44b8-8a72-7d03c05e6ff4/calendars/AAMkAGI0Mjk2NTQ5LTE4MjctNDE1Yy04Nzc0LWIxNzA0MDBkNDkwZABGAAAAAABAJhtsoNeXR49KeByGVNbsBwB0tR3-uC1cSqrKkE00IGLeAAAAAAEGAAB0tR3-uC1cSqrKkE00IGLeAAAAAB89AAA=/events`

There is no direct call to get all events from all the calendars as of now. There is already a feature request raised in the [Microsoft Graph Feature Request Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/33990883-create-event-in-all-calendars), please upvote it so that it may be implemented in the future.